# C# Extending generic method

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods, generic-programming

Good day,

Is there a way to extend generic method?
for example

i have such method:

```
public T DoSomethingAboutIt<T>()
{
//do magic
}
```

what i want to is to have extended method
such as:

```
private static T Extended<T, L>(this T o, Func<T, L> func)
{
    return default(T);
}
```

Is this extension is possible?

edit:
i would like to call it like this something DoSomethingAboutIt().Extended...

Comment: Sure, that's possible. What's your problem?

Comment: Really not sure what you're asking. I do think it's possible. Did you try it and get an error or something?

Comment: Well i tried it of course, just doesn't work. I would like to know how to do it. Could you redirect me somewhere where i could start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible but you still have to follow the rules of [Extension Methods (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx).

This code compiles just fine...

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int y = 1;
        int z = y.Extended(n => "hi!");
    }
}

public static class X
{
    public static T Extended<T, L>(this T o, Func<T, L> func)
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this works indeed, thank you. I guess i am already tired...My gratitude